# How to make test coverage show all vue files in Vue-cli 3 using jest

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, vue-cli-3, nyc

I am having difficulty trying to set up Vue CLI 3 with Jest to show test coverage. I have done everything possible to make it work, but it is still showing no coverage:

```
Ran all test suites.
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|

=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Branches     : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Functions    : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Lines        : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
```

Below is an excerpt of my configuration:

*jest.config.js:*

```js
module.exports = {
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'js',
    'jsx',
    'json',
    'vue'
  ],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.vue$': 'vue-jest',
    '.+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|svg|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$': 'jest-transform-stub',
    '^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest'
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1'
  },
  snapshotSerializers: [
    'jest-serializer-vue'
  ],
  testMatch: [
    '**/tests/unit/**/*.spec.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)|**/__tests__/*.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'
  ],
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/'],
  testURL: 'http://localhost/'
}
```

*package.json:*

```
....
"scripts": {
  "test:unit": "nyc vue-cli-service test:unit"
},
"nyc": {
  "check-coverage": true,
  "per-file": true,
  "lines": 90,
  "statements": 90,
  "functions": 90,
  "branches": 90,
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.{js,vue}"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "src/*.js"
  ],
  "reporter": [
    "lcov",
    "text",
    "text-summary"
  ],
  "extension": [
    ".js",  
    ".vue"
  ],
  "verbose": true,
  "cache": true,
  "all": true
}
```

How do I properly configure Vue CLI 3 and Jest to show test coverage?

Answer (score 24):

Jest has its own coverage facilities, so remove `nyc` from *package.json:*

```
"scripts": {
  // "test:unit": "nyc vue-cli-service test:unit" // DELETE
  "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit"
},
// "nyc": {...} // DELETE
```

To enable Jest's coverage, set [`collectCoverage`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#collectcoverage-boolean) and [`collectCoverageFrom`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#collectcoveragefrom-array) in *jest.config.js* (per the [`vue-test-utils` docs](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/#testing-single-file-components-with-jest)):

```
collectCoverage: true,
collectCoverageFrom: [
  'src/**/*.{js,vue}',
  '!src/main.js', // No need to cover bootstrap file
],
```

Running `yarn test:unit` should yield console output like this:

[image: console screenshot]

[GitHub demo](https://github.com/tony19-sandbox/vue-jest-coverage)

Also note that the Jest console output only lists files that contain executable JavaScript (`methods` for Vue SFCs). If you're working off the default Vue CLI generated template, `HelloWorld.vue` contains no `methods`, so it won't be listed. In the screenshot above, I've added an unused method to `HelloWorld.vue` to demonstrate Jest's uncovered lines report.

Comment: That's not broken; rather it's working as intended. That output simply tells you the tests in `example.spec.js` does not cover line 9 in `App.vue`. See updated screenshot (showing `App.vue` lines covered by newly added `app.spec.js`) and [github demo](https://github.com/tony19-sandbox/vue-jest-coverage).

Answer (score 13):

While @tony19's answer is perfectly valid, you don't necessarily need to add anything in your custom jest configuration. For a project built with the Vue CLI service, just adding the following script in the `package.json` worked fine, and the coverage is showing up for Vue components:

```
"test:coverage": "vue-cli-service test:unit --coverage",
```

There are additional options you can add, such as changing the reporter(s), and having a distinct Jest configuration just for this script. To get the full list of options, you can run the following command in your terminal:

```
 npx vue-cli-service test:unit help
```

And, among these options, you'll find `collectCoverage` and `collectCoverageFrom` which can help you keep everything in the script, rather than having a custom config file.

Comment: Indeed, another way to tackle this is to use the Jest CLI via `test:unit` :) If Vue CLI was used to generate the project with `@vue/unit-jest`, the project would already contain Jest configs either in `jest.config.js` (if `useConfigFiles` enabled), or in `package.json`'s `jest` property. I'd argue that it would be cleaner to keep all Jest configs in the same location rather than separating one/some of them in an `npm` script.

Comment: coverage folder is generated but how to get the report file in XML

Answer (score 9):

If you don't use Vue CLI plugin `@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest`, you can still generate test coverage report for Vue components. You can have Jest configured similar to the following way:

**jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'json', 'vue'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.vue$': 'vue-jest'
  },
  collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: ['src/**/*.{js,vue}', '!src/main.js']
}
```

Then you can generate the coverage report by simply running `npx jest`.

The coverage reports will look like below:

**(1) Terminal**
[image]

**(2) HTML**
[image]

Comment: Able to get the coverage, how to get the JUnit report in XML
using vue3-jest 27.0.0-alpha.4